# bottleで@route('/hello/')を用意してもトップページが404になる

Tags: python, bottle

## 目標: python3で「hello,world」とブラウザ表示させること

`http://localhost:8080/` と `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` の2つのURLでアクセスを試しましたが、以下のエラーが表示されてしまいます。

> Error: 404 Not Found
>   Sorry, the requested URL 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/' caused an error:
>   Not found: '/'

コマンドプロンプトに表示されたログ：

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 16:57:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 720
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 16:58:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 720
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 16:58:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 720
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 16:59:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 720
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 16:59:07] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 742
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 17:32:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 720
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 17:32:18] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 742
```

「hello.py」の内容は次の通りです。

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/')
def index(name):
    return template('Hello {{name}}!', name=name)

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

ブラウザは、Google Chrome と Microsoft Edge の両方で試しました。
OSはWindows7、 anacondaインストールして、python3使ってます。
考えられる原因と解決策を具体的におしえてくださると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `name` を引数に取るので `@route('/hello/<name>')` とするのではないでしょうか。また、関数名は `def hello(name):` とした方が良いかと思います。変更後、アクセスする URL は例えば `http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello/yasasa` などとします。

Comment: unaristさん、回答ありがとうございます。
ソースを修正して、URLを「http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello/ysasa」
にしたら、できました。ありがとうございます。
やっと、次に進めます。これからも頑張ります。

Comment: あっ、metripolisさんだったか。間違えました、すいません

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/41807 マルチポスト

Comment: multipost  http://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/9987

Answer (score 2):

`def index(name):`という形で、`name`を引数に取る関数を用意しているので`@route('/hello/<name>')` とするのではないでしょうか。
また、関数名は`def hello(name):`とした方が良いかと思います。
変更後、アクセスする URL は例えば`http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello/yasasa` などとします。